# What is a good VR GUI toolkit?

Tags: user-interface, virtual-reality, toolkit

Is there a good GUI for VR? Scaleform is no longer supported. Coherent seems like an option. I just don't know how to integrate it if it is not natively supported by the engine. IMGUI seems like it is limited in the look that can be created by it. Are there any others?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at Qt? It's very flexible and works on a variety of different platforms. QtQuick/QML in particular is pretty nice for VR interfaces.

Here is a video of a talk from Qt World Summit 2017 that does a pretty good job of summarizing the current state of things: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RtcmVbicZWw (Basically, the maintainers of Qt are working on a lot of cool VR-related things). I don't work for them and have only starting using Qt recently, but from what I've seen so far it works very well for this purpose.

In particular, take a look at QQuickRenderControl (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickrendercontrol.html). This class allows full control over rendering of QML content to a framebuffer. Right now I'm using it in the creation of SteamVR overlays.